# How to remove the slashes and characters added by JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Im working on a to do list app with ajax. 
When I enter data in the following php file into the database is works very  well:

```
<?php 
require 'databaseConnection.php';

$date = $_POST['dueDate'];
$importance = $_POST['importance'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$sql="INSERT INTO tasklist
VALUES (Null,'$date','$importance','$description')";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
 $data = "<tr> <td>".$date."</td>
        <td>".$importance."</td>
        <td>".$description."</td>
        <td><i class='fas fa-trash'<></i></td></tr>";
        echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

But when I send the $data variable back to the Jquery/Ajax I get the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I remove the extra "\r\n\t" ?

This is my jquery

```
request = $.ajax({
                    url: "./backend/enterIntoTaskList.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: serializedData
                });

                request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    console.log(JSON.parse(response));
                });

                 request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                    console.error(
                        "The following error occurred: "+
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                });
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to json encode html?

Comment: Also there is a syntax error before the `</i>`

Comment: `JSON.parse()` removes them, what's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar It didn't remove this, that`s why I am asking.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't. But I agree with @Taplar -- there's no need to use `json_encode()` in the first place, just echo the HTML.

Comment: Now it works!! I thought I had to do this cause Ajax is aspecting a json response!

Comment: Nothing about ajax says json is required.  Ajax, at its root, is simply a web request that does not cause a page transfer.  That's it.